# Как сравнить содержимое нескольких элементов с основным?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Имеется div в котором есть дочерние элементы. В дочерних элементах написано время (к примеру: 13:00, 14:00, 15:00), везде разное.
Также есть div с текущим временем.
Подскажите как скрыть элементы в которых время (число) меньше чем в блоке с текущим временем?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each($('.myClass'), function() {
      if($(this).text() < $('.currentTime').text())
              $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Это самоответ или дополнение к вопросу?